# Is google drive api for c# thread safe?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, thread-safety, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using [google drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) in a multi-thread C# application. I would like to know if the [Google dot net client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) it's thread-safe or not.

Also I would like to know what's more right:

create a singelton service, or a new service every time.

Comment: I think its up to you if your code is thread safe or not.

Comment: You mean google drive library does not take care of it?
And do you know how I should create the service: once or for each request? thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any mention of the Google .net client library.   Only the Google Drive API.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I meant Google Drive Api

Comment: you might want to move the singleton part to another question.

Comment: I really wanted, but I had to wait 90 minute, so I put it here for now. I'm gonna move it soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking if the [Google .net client Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) is thread safe. I am pretty sure that it is.  It is noted in at least one place in the documentation that it is thread safe.

[Google APIs Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth)

> UserCredential is a thread-safe helper class for using an access token
>   to access protected resources. An access token typically expires after
>   1 hour, after which you will get an error if you try to use it.

Comment: I saw that too, but if it is mentioned only there (I couldn't find more places), doesn't that mean that only this is thread-safe?

Comment: Don't think so but I can ping the Developer on the project and find out for sure.   Please go read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The library main classes are thread-safe, such as Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest, Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService and Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential (as you mentioned). There are other classes which are not, such as the resources themselves. So, regarding your question, services and requests are implemented as thread-safe. There is only one issue that I'm aware of - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=466, and the main problem there is when you use several MediaUpload method in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't.  I've tried writing some code assuming it was, and my code would sometimes randomly crash at the "request.Execute()"s...

I tried using a mutex and so only one thread was using a singleton service at a time: that reduced the crashes but it didn't eliminate them.

Leaving the mutex in, I changed it to a singleton UserCredential and use a new service for each thread and it hasn't crashed since.  (I don't know if I need the mutex anymore or not, but the google api calls aren't critical path for my application, I just needed to get the calls out of the main thread.)